# Can I use str_replace twice in one string?

Tags: php, str-replace

```
<?php
echo "I'm currently listening to</a> <a href='http://last.fm/artist/" . str_replace(" ","+",$artist) . "/_/"  . str_replace(" ","+",$currenttrack) . "'>" . $currenttrack . "</a>";
?>
```

Above is my code. I'm trying to use `str_replace()` again on `$artist` and `$currenttrack` like:

`str_replace("'","%27",$artist)` and  `str_replace("'","%27",$currenttrack)`

because the apostrophe doesn't go through correctly and messes with my code, but when I use it first with the spaces, it's already passed and won't change again.

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do multiple replacements on the same string, you can pass arrays to `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(array(" ", "'"), array("+", "%27"), $artist)
```

However, when creating URL parameters, you shouldn't do the replacements yourself. You should use `urlencode`, and it will do all the necessary encodings.

Comment: +1 .. don't know why someone downvoted this answer, it's the only one which actually solves it using str_replace

Comment: although you could do that using `strtr` like this: `strtr($artist, array(" " => "+", "'" => "%27"));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It also makes your code more readable. Also, your anchor tags aren't formatted correctly.

```
$artist = str_replace(' ', '+', $artist);
$track = str_replace(' ', '%27', $currenttrack);

echo 'I\'m currently listening to <a href="http://last.fm/artist/' . $artist . '/_/' . $track . '">' . $track . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to replace spaces by + and ' by %27 in the two strings. To achieve this, you have to apply `str_replace()` on the result of the first operation. If `$input` is the original string, use:

```
$intermediate = str_replace(" ", "+", $input);
$result = str_replace("'", "%27", $intermediate);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function to do the same you are trying to do: `urlencode`

```
$currenttrack = $artist = "X' xx WWW' w";

$url = "http://last.fm/artist/" . $artist . "/_/"  . $currenttrack;

echo urlencode($url); // http%3A%2F%2Flast.fm%2Fartist%2FX%27+xx+WWW%27+w%2F_%2FX%27+xx+WWW%27+w
```